# How to prove the function $\sin(x)$ is not onto

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

\begin{align}
f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\:f\left(x\right)=\sin\left(x\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
I know that it is not onto because for all values of $y$ past $[-1,1]$ there is no $x$.

Graphically it makes sense but I'm finding it hard to do an actual proof for this function.

Comment: contest-math?${}$

Comment: Looking at the earlier answers, you seem to have changed from "one to one" to "onto".  It depends on your definition of sine, but note that the hypotenuse is the longest side of a real triangle ($x^2+y^2 \ge x^2$ so $\left|\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \le 1$) and so there is no $x$ with $\sin(x)=2$

Answer (score 7):

Since $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, we see that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x\le 1$. Therefore
$$
-1\le |\sin x|\le 1
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, there's no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin x=42$.

<sub>Why $42$? Well, that's obvious! `;-)`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

To show it is not one-to-one:

You only need to find two values $x_1, x_2$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $\sin(x_1) = \sin(x_2)$.

When you draw your "horizontal line test" the $x$-coordinates of the points of intersection are the $x_1$ and $x_2$ you want.

> Explicitly, $x_1 = 0, x_2 = \pi$ will work nicely.

To show it is not onto:

Just assert that there is no $x$ such that $\sin(x) = 2$, this is a reasonably "common" fact that I would think you are allowed to draw on.

Comment: Doesn't that show that isn't injective?

Comment: Yes, of course. Either I wasn't paying close attention to the question or the question was edited.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the definition for a surjection, $\forall y \in \mathbb R \exists  x\in \mathbb R  (f(x)=y)$ but since $2\not \in Im f$...

Answer (score 2):

The sine is not onto because there is no real number $x$ such that $\sin x = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The sine function on the entire real line cannot be one to one because the values of the map repeat every integral multiple of $\pi/2$. By definition, such a function cannot be one to one.

It cannot be onto $\mathbb{R}$ either because $\max\sin = 1$ and $\min\sin = -1$. Therefore, for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ whose absolute value is greater than $1$, $x$ is not in the range of the sine function.

However, you can restrict the domain of sine in such a manner that it **is** one to one, such as from $0$ to $\pi/2$. On this restricted domain,the function is both one to one and onto. Which is why we can define the inverse sine function on this domain.

Comment: Please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to write mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

A function is one to one may have different meanings. (1) one to one from x to f(x). (2) one to one from f(x) to x, and (3) both ways.

When you say, when y is out of [-1, +1], there is no x, that is the case-2 being not true. Further, since there exists multiple x values to one y in sin(x), that is the case-1 being not true.

Comment: Saying that a function $f:A\to B$ is one-to-one has exactly one meaning. There is not any ambiguity. It means ONLY that distinct points in the domain are mapped to distinct points in the range.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin x$ is  periodic with period $2\pi$, it is enough to consider $\sin x$ over the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Also $\sin x$ being a continuous function defined on a compact subset $[0,2\pi]$, range of $\sin x$ must be a compact subset i.e. a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. So the range of  $\sin x$ cannot be whole of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are letting $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \sin(x)$, then, as others have pointed out, $f(x) = \sin(x)$ will not be onto because $\sin(x)\neq\gamma\in\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$; that is, not *every* value in $\mathbb{R}$ will be obtained by plugging in values from $\mathbb{R}$.

However, it may help you to consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$, where $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Can you see why *this* function would be onto as opposed to when $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?